# MySQL CASE...WHERE...THEN statements

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I have a MySQL UPDATE statement that uses a CASE clause

```
UPDATE partsList SET quantity =  
CASE
  WHEN partFK = 1 THEN 4
  WHEN partFK = 2 THEN 8
END
WHERE buildFK = 1;
```

The above statement works. Yet when I remove one of the WHEN statements, it breaks and the error indicates the CASE clause isn't returning anything. Is it that the CASE clause must have more than one WHEN to function.

I don't know beforehand how many updates I'll need, so I'm trying to build a single update statement that can handle one or many updates.

Thanks for any insights you can provide.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

It isn't that the `CASE` must have more than one, `WHEN...THEN`, it's that it must handle all the data you give it.

If you removed one of the clauses, you leave a hole. e.g.

```
UPDATE partsList SET quantity =  
CASE
  WHEN partFK = 1 THEN 4
END
WHERE buildFK = 1;
```

With this update statement, if `parkFK` is 2, then the update fails because the CASE can't handle the input.

You can either limit your source data by adding another line to your where-clause (e.g. `AND partFK in (1,2)`), or you could add an `ELSE` to the case expression.

```
UPDATE partsList SET quantity =  
CASE
  WHEN partFK = 1 THEN 4
  WHEN partFK = 2 THEN 8
  ELSE 12 
END
WHERE buildFK = 1;
```

However, based on the SQL statement you've shown, there is probably a better way. Presumably, partFK is a foreign-key to some other table. Can you pull the value for `quantity` from there?

Comment: Ahh, I see. I had read that the database evaluates the CASE on each row, so that makes sense now.The table is a link between builds and parts, this table is where the quantity is stored. Can I use the current value in the ELSE? I.e. ELSE quantity

Comment: Awesome, thanks for clearing that up for me. And for the record, `ELSE quantity` did work.

Comment: For reference https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/case.html

Answer (score 1):

Add `ELSE NULL` or something before the `END` of the case. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-statement.html for more info.

Answer (score 0):

**MS SQL Server** version of sql statement would be as following:

```
Update partsList SET quantity = 
CASE partFK 
 WHEN 1 THEN 4
 WHEN 2 THEN 8
END
```