# Using CASE to update column value depending on other column values

Tags: mysql, sql

For simplicity say I have a column 'Hour' which is either the value 10, or 12. I wish to update a new column, Hour_type which will be 'A' if the Hour value is 10 or B if 12 and so on. I can output a column, 'Hour_type' by using CASE, as follows

```
SELECT CASE WHEN Hour = 10 then 'A'
            WHEN hour = 12 then 'B'
            else 'c'
        end
as Hour_type
from Traffic_Counts
```

This outputs the correct answer but does not insert the values into the table.

I wish to set a column which exists in the table with these values.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN Hour = 10 then 'A'
            WHEN hour = 12 then 'B'
        end
as Hour_type
from Traffic_Counts set Hour_type = Hour_type
```

This results in a Syntax error.

In pseudocode I am trying to add an 'if' to this simple update column

```
update table set Hour_type = 'a' if Hour = 10,
                             'b' if Hour = 12;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `case [...] end` block is an expression. `update` is used to `set` columns from expressions. So, just take the entire `case [...] end` block and make that the right-hand-side of an `update` to your desired column. This would work for any other `select`able expression, too (barring conflicting types, etc.)

Comment: Thanks. I tried, is this what you mean?
update Hour_type SELECT CASE WHEN Hour = 10 then Hour_type = 'A'
            WHEN hour = 12 then Hour_type = 'B'
            else Hour_type = 'c'
        end

Comment: Close... but please learn the syntax of `update`. It would be `update yourTable set yourColumn = yourExpression[, yourOtherColumn = blahBlah];` where the square brackets are optional and can be repeated for multiple columns. So, in this case, `update yourTable set yourColumn = case [...] end`.

Comment: Many thansk for the help. So, I tried "update Traffic_Counts set Hour_type = case [when Hour = 10 then 'A', when Hour = 12 then 'B', else 'C'] end"  but no avail. Am I correct in saying there should be , between the different when statements?

Comment: No, there should not be commas there. As I said, just put in the `case` block the same as it was in the original `select`. And the square brackets were just shorthand to indicate I was missing out code; do not include those. Plenty more info could be found in the documentation for these keywords.

Answer (score 1):

Use this, but i am not sure what are you doing.
This return 'a', 'b' or 'X' if the HOUR not 10 or 12

```
update table set Hour_type = IF(HOUR = 10 , 'a', IF(HOUR = 12, 'b', 'X'));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use case statement to update records.Go through the link for query

[MySQL CASE...WHERE...THEN statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8348037/mysql-case-where-then-statements)