# Update Set, match a single column, multiple values for different IDs in single query

Tags: mysql

How can I do this:

```
UPDATE `TEST_TABLE` SET `C1` = 'VALUE_FOR_ID1' WHERE `ID` = 1;
UPDATE `TEST_TABLE` SET `C1` = 'VALUE_FOR_ID2' WHERE `ID` = 2;
UPDATE `TEST_TABLE` SET `C1` = 'VALUE_FOR_ID3' WHERE `ID` = 3;
```

With a single query with a matching (something like this):

```
UPDATE `TEST_TABLE` SET `C1` = ('VALUE_FOR_ID1','VALUE_FOR_ID2','VALUE_FOR_ID3') WHERE `ID` IN (1,2,3);
```

Comment: Update with case perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8348037/mysql-case-where-then-statements

Comment: P.Salmon, This is not what I want. I need an update in a single query, where the value of the column I want to update will take a sequence of values, and will match the same sequence of IDs. TY anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this using **CASE**:

```
UPDATE  TEST_TABLE SET C1 =  
CASE
  WHEN ID = 1 THEN 'VALUE_FOR_ID1'
  WHEN ID = 2 THEN 'VALUE_FOR_ID2'
  WHEN ID = 3 THEN 'VALUE_FOR_ID3'
END
WHERE ID IN (1,2,3)
```

Comment: It Works . TY Gabriel Gates .
Is this the most efficient way to do it?

Comment: I can't say for sure, definitely depends on the situation and the code creating the query (guessing PHP in your case) but I usually prefer to make fewer requests to the database. In this 'case' you have three so you wouldn't see a difference, however, I have used this approach to make load routines faster. For example instead of 500 separate updates, you could build one query to execute.

Comment: Yes, Gabriel Gates, i'll use it in php, and i want avoid multiple requests. In my case i want replace  +2000 requests for an single query. Let's see if it worth (i hope so). TY

Comment: I did this a while ago, and I believe I hit a point where the query was just too large. I can't remember exactly how many records but as an example if I had 2000 records to update, I would break it out into four queries each updating 500 records.

Comment: Okay, I'll take your helpful advices. TY