# Can i UPDATE not insert, multiple values for one row with diferente conditions?

Tags: php, mysql

i need to update my table `document_Format` that has a Column named `NumVias`, and the table has a row called  `CodFormatoCategoria`
. What i have is this:

```
'UPDATE document_Format
                SET NumVias = "'.$Campos['NumVias_Vendas'].'" 
                WHERE CodFormatoCategoria = "VEND" and CodEmpresa = "'.$CodEmpresa.'" '
```

What i need is like:

```
'UPDATE CodFormatoCategoria 
                SET NumVias = "'.$Campos['NumVias_Vendas'].'" 
                WHERE CodFormatoCategoria = "VEND",

                SET NumVias = "'.$Campos['NumVias_Compras'].'" 
                WHERE CodFormatoCategoria = "COMP",

                SET NumVias = "'.$Campos['NumVias_Diversos'].'" 
                WHERE CodFormatoCategoria = "DIV",

 and CodEmpresa = "'.$CodEmpresa.'" '
```

IS this possible without running the function 3 times? Can i do it in one query?

Comment: Have a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8348037/mysql-case-where-then-statements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `CASE` statement to conditionally choose a value for the column. If there were no matches for any `CASE WHEN` statement, you can set an `ELSE` statement to keep the original value, so nothing changes.

```php
$sql = "UPDATE CodFormatoCategoria 
           SET NumVias = CASE WHEN CodFormatoCategoria = 'VEND' THEN '".$Campos['NumVias_Vendas']."' 
                              WHEN CodFormatoCategoria = 'COMP' THEN '".$Campos['NumVias_Compras']."' 
                              WHEN CodFormatoCategoria = 'DIV' THEN '".$Campos['NumVias_Diversos']."' 
                              ELSE NumVias 
                          END
            WHERE CodEmpresa = '".$CodEmpresa."'";
```

Comment: Thanks Qirel that worked great! Ive tried that before but i was having some syntax issues! Thanks alot!