# Update values of one column with multiple values

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

There is a table and that table has a column with a name country and I need to change values at that column in one query instead of multiple queries.

In this query, I change any value with Egypt to be 1

```
UPDATE subscribers
SET country = 1 WHERE country = 'Egypt';
```

in this query, I change any value with Qatar to be 2

```
UPDATE subscribers
SET country = 2 WHERE country = 'Qatar';
```

Any help to make these two queries in one?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: ...or just execute a query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `case` expression in MySQL:

```
UPDATE subscribers
    SET country = (CASE WHEN country = 'Egypt' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END)
    WHERE country IN ('Egypt', 'Qatar');
```

However, I would recommend using a derived table:

```
UPDATE subscribers s JOIN
       (SELECT 'Egypt' as country, '1' as new_country UNION ALL
        SELECT 'Qatar' as country, '2' as new_country 
       ) x
       USING (country)  
    SET s.country = x.new_country;
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

```
UPDATE subscribers SET country =  
CASE
  WHEN country = "Egypt" THEN 1
  WHEN country = "Qatar" THEN 2
  ELSE country 
END
;
```

Now imagine doing that expression for many more countries. Instead join to a table that 'maps' data association (a master table of country names). Join on CountryName fields and update destination table CountryName field with ID from 'mapping' table. Convert to number type field. Or play it safe and update to another field and when all looks good, delete the original field.

Comment: I got that error
ERROR 1305 (42000): FUNCTION pinsubmit.Switch does not exist

Comment: Query works for me. But I am using Access. Sorry, just noticed you are using MySQL. MySQL might use CASE. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8348037/mysql-case-where-then-statements