# if/elseif/else statement not working as it should

Tags: php, mysql, sql

As the title says I have a problem running an if/elseif/else statement query, long story short it's not entering the condition correctly.

Here is the PHP code

```
<?php 

$time = $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME'];
$query0 = "SELECT lastco FROM customers";
$query_run0 = mysqli_query($conn, $query0);

if(mysqli_num_rows($query_run0) > 0)
{
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_run0))
    {
        if($row['lastco'] < $time-300)
        {
            if($row['lastco'] < $time-2000000)
            {
                $query1 = "UPDATE customers SET customer_status='Not Registered' WHERE lastco < $time-2000000";
                $query_run1 = mysqli_query($conn, $query1);
            }
            else
            {
                $query2 = "UPDATE customers SET customer_status='Offline' WHERE lastco < $time-300";
                $query_run2 = mysqli_query($conn, $query2);
            }
            
        }
        elseif($row['lastco'] > $time-300)
        {
            $query3 = "UPDATE customers SET customer_status='Online' WHERE lastco > $time-300";
            $query_run3 = mysqli_query($conn, $query3);
        }
    }
}?>
```

So the problem is that instead of modifying the customer_status row to 'Not Registered' it will just modify it to 'Offline', and never edit the row to 'Not Registered' even if the condition is fulfilled so what can I do to make that statement work that way ?

Comment: Why do you do it in PHP instead of SQL?

Comment: The behavior described pretty strongly implies that `$row['lastco'] < $time-2000000` evaluates to `false`.  Do you have any information which would indicate that it shouldn't?  *Edit:* Which records do you expect will satisfy the condition `WHERE lastco < $time-2000000` but **won't** satisfy the condition `WHERE lastco < $time-300`?

Comment: If's work perfectly, the data you provide it or the format that data is in is more likely your problem. Start by adding an `echo $row['lastco'];` _[Debug 101]_

Comment: @Dharman what do you mean ?

Comment: Why do you first SELECT and then UPDATE? Can't you do it all in a single UPDATE without any SELECT?

Comment: @SharpIt777: This is a good opportunity for you to do some debugging and observe/confirm the behavior of the code.  I suspect what's happening is that the `if` condition works just fine and you *are* updating records to "Not Registered", but later in your loop when you update records to "Offline" you're overwriting *all* of the previously updated records.  (Though why you're repeating these operations in a loop at all seems... unnecessary.)

Comment: @David good question, $row['lastco'] is equal to $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME']; in the db, i use it to check for my customers status, so if for example in the 1st customer lastco field there is '10' it should obviously enter that $time-2000000 conditions, and UPDATE it to Not Registered instead of Offline

Comment: Heads up! This code doesn't have a path for the case where `$row['lastco'] == $time-300`. There probably should be a `<=` rather than a `<` in one of those if clauses.

Comment: Please do not add answers to the question body itself. Instead, you should add it as an answer. [Answering your own question is allowed and even encouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `if` conditions works just fine.  Instead of defaulting to the assumption that `if` is somehow broken, examine your logic.  Start by putting that logic into simple descriptions:

```
For *every record*, repeat:
  If some value is below 300
    If some value is below 2000000
      Update *all values* that are below 2000000
    Else
      Update *all values* that are below 300
  Else, if some value is above 300
    Update *all values* that are above 300
```

So... If each iteration of the loop is meant to *update all values*, then why do you need to repeat that operation in a loop at all?

And, more to the point here... When you `Update *all values* that are below 300`, why do you expect that wouldn't also `Update *all values* that are below 2000000`?  After all, any number which is lower than 300 is *also* lower than 2000000.

Scrap the loop and all the if/else blocks entirely.  Just perform the updates you want to perform:

```
Update *all values* that are below 2000000
Update *all values* that are below 300
Update *all values* that are above 300
```

Forget the `SELECT`, forget the loop, just execute your three `UPDATE` statements to update your data.  (You *could* do it in one `UPDATE` statement, but for clarity let's just start with removing all the cruft of that loop.)

Comment: Working perfectly, thanks for your answer, may I ask you how to do it into only 1 query instead of 3 like i did ?

Comment: @SharpIt777: You can make use of [a `CASE` structure](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8348037/328193) in your `UPDATE` operation, conditionally defining the value to be updated.